# PHP 5.3.3 _server['query_string'] ERROR

Tags: php, wordpress, version

I'm using wordpress on a PHP server 5.3.3 and i got error when i try to get the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

My code below:

```
$query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];     

if($current_user->user_nicename == "admin"){
    echo '<a class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple" href="#" target="_blank" >Lista cursos</a>';
      if(isset($_GET['demo'])){ 
          if (strpos($query_string,'&demo') !== false)
            $enlacesindemo = str_replace("&demo","",$query_string);
      }
}
?>
        <a  class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple" href="index.php?<?= $enlacesindemo ?>" target="_self">Ver todos</a>
```

And i got this as link:

```
index.php?<?= $query_string ?>&demo
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: the link does not print like i want, printed that:
index.php? <?= query_string ?>&demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[short_open_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) in not enabled by your server.

try using `<?php ?>` instead of `<? ?>`

And `<?php echo $variable;?>` instead of `<?=$variable;?>`

Comment: Thanks!! thats all i want!